# Understanding how R calculates deviance residuals

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to understand how R calculates deviance residuals. In R documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/binomTools/versions/1.0-1/topics/Residuals). The formula is

[image: Equation for Deviance Residual Calculation]

```
i = c(0,1,1)
o = c(1,0,0)
m = glm(o~i, family = "binomial")
residuals(m, type = "deviance")
#            1             2             3 
# 1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05

m$fitted.values
#            1            2            3 
# 1.000000e+00 5.826215e-11 5.826215e-11
```

When I go through the formula with y = 1, y^ = 1, and n = 3, the formula gives 0 as answer. However, the residual as observed is non-zero.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to embed the image due to less reputation.

Comment: Using an example without complete separation would be better

Comment: Do not use a rounded value of y-hat. It is not 1 but slightly smaller than 1 for the first data point: see `1 - fitted(m)`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai what does n_i represent? Could you give an example with n_i = 2 say?

Comment: @Roland ah yes! that works!

Comment: @DarrenTsai I'm still not sure what you mean. What do you mean by "combination of predictor values"? Are you trying to say that this n_i would change if I try to predict something with a Bernoulli distribution? 

Could you point me to a link where I could read more on this. The R documentation doesn't mention what n_i is.

Comment: "Could you give an example where for some i, n_i = 2 say?" this would really clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code calculates the deviance residuals from the formula.

[image]

```
y <- c(1, 0, 0)
y.hat <- fitted(m)

# part 1
part1 <- sign(y - y.hat)

# part 2
part2 <- 2 * log(y / y.hat) * y
part2[is.nan(part2)] <- 0

# part 3
part3 <- 2 * (1-y) * log((1-y)/(1-y.hat))
part3[is.nan(part3)] <- 0

# result
(dr <- part1 * sqrt(part2 + part3))
#            1             2             3 
# 1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05
```

***Note***

- In the calculation of part 2 and part 3, `NaN` will appear because `"0 x log(0)"`. Here we take its limit 0.
- n_i are always 1 in a ungrouped data which the response variable is recorded as raw 0 and 1.

***Comparison***

```
residuals(m, type = "deviance")
#            1             2             3 
# 1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05 -1.079465e-05 

all.equal(dr, residuals(m, type = "deviance"))
# [1] TRUE
```

---

If you sum up the successes at each combination of the predictor variables, then the data becomes "grouped" or "aggregated". It looks like

```
X success failure  n
0       1       0  1
1       0       2  2
```

In this form, the calculation will be

```
success <- c(1, 0) ; fail <- c(0, 2) ; x <- c(0, 1)
m2 <- glm(cbind(success, fail) ~ x, binomial())
y <- success
n <- success + fail
y.hat <- n * fitted(m2)
part1 <- sign(y - y.hat)
part2 <- 2 * log(y / y.hat) * y
part2[is.nan(part2)] <- 0
part3 <- 2 * (n-y) * log((n-y)/(n-y.hat))
part3[is.nan(part3)] <- 0
(dr <- part1 * sqrt(part2 + part3))
#            1             2 
# 1.079465e-05 -1.290299e-05
```

Comment: For a Binomial regression model won't the range of the response variable always be {0,1}. I really don't understand when n_i's would be different from 1. Also, thanks a lot, Darren!

Comment: @user1752323 n_i depend on which form of data you have, i.e. ungrouped or grouped. In the former, each row is assumed to have a Bernoulli distribution. In the latter, each row is assumed to have a Binomial distribution with n = n_i.